# Update EXE used by different processes

Tags: c#, process, exe, .net-assembly

My project will load an EXE into a process by demand. So there will be multiple processes using the same EXE. They are working well. But now we met a problem that if we want to update the EXE , then we have to stop all processes. We might need only update one of the processes, others maybe later. So we planed to pragmatically creating dedicated folder for each process and so each process will use its own EXE. That might work, but still wondering if there are any framework or best practice for this situation.

```
using (Process botProcess = new Process())
{
    botProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("bot.exe");
    botProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = bot.Name;
    //ssnavBotAppProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    botProcess.Start();
    processList.Add(bot.Id, botProcess.Id.ToString());
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, just a caution, If you are planning to release this application (logic as a part of your application), there are chances that antivirus software may consider this behavior (loading ".exe" pragmatically) as harmful for computer and block your application.

Comment: Can you rename the exe even while processes are using it? Then put the new exe with the original name, and any process that is restarted will pick up the new one.